# Generic argument

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

I would like to create an Java interface with a method that accepts all subtypes of a type:

```
interface A{};

interface B{
  void method(A a);
}
```

What I want to accomplish is to make an implementation of the method(A a) accept
all subtypes of A (like return type polymorphism but with an argument).

Is this even possible?

Comment: It already accepts all subtypes of `A`.

Comment: Your current method will indeed accept all subtypes of `A`.

Answer (score 5):

You've already done it!

To prove it, try something like this:

```
public class ThisA implements A {}
public class ThatA implements A {}
public class OtherA implements A {}
public class SubclassA extends OtherA {}
```

then call your method:

```
B b = new B {
  public void method(A a) {
    System.out.println("Called with "+a);
  }
}

b.method(new ThisA());
b.method(new ThatA());
b.method(new OtherA());
b.method(new SubclassA());
```